# How to Stop Mouse Click in Echo Area from Opening Message Buffer?

Tags: key-bindings, echo-area

Clicking the echo area causes Emacs to switch to the `*Messages*` buffer.

I **hate** this behavior, because the only time I click the echo area is on accident, whereupon it wastes time and breaks train of thought as I have to interrupt what I was trying to do with burying the messages buffer.

How do I disable it, so that clicking the echo area does nothing? (I know that mouse clicks are bound just like any other key,  but I don't know what keymap to use?

And since the echo area alternates between showing the contents of  `*Minibuf-0*`,  `*Echo Area 0*`, and  `*Echo Area 1*` buffers, the latter two of which can be deleted and get automatically recreated, I don't know if it needs to be done in some mode or minibuffer setup hook?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**STEP 1**:  Type `C-h k` and then left mouse click inside the echo area.

**STEP 2**:  Read through the `*Help*` buffer and observe the message that reads:

```
<mouse-1> at that spot runs the command view-echo-area-messages (found
in minibuffer-inactive-mode-map), which is an interactive
byte-compiled Lisp function in ‘help.el’.
```

**STEP 3**:  Redefine or disable the offending keyboard shortcut.  To make sure that you have found the correct mode-map, it might be helpful to set up a message such as:

```lisp
(define-key minibuffer-inactive-mode-map [mouse-1]
   (lambda () (interactive) (message "hello-world")))
```

**STEP 4**:  Then, after verifying the above-mentioned definition works as advertised, go ahead and change the function parameter to either `nil` or `'ignore`:

```lisp
(define-key minibuffer-inactive-mode-map [mouse-1] nil)
```

Comment: Big thanks! I wrongly assumed that in this one specific case, `describe-key` wouldn't work, since I'm used to it needing to run "in" the buffer that has the binding.